# Removing last item of a listview

Tags: android, listview

It shows no error but the app crash when i click the button to remove the last item in the list view. List view works fine with the arraylist... just when i want to remove the last item, it gives me a crash.

```
btnUndo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = adapter.getCount();
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(count));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are 0-based, so you should do the following:

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(count - 1));
```

I also suggest to use `notifyItemRemoved`
 instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`.