# Remove the last view added to a list view when a button is pressed

Tags: android

With the valuable help of Shy Ward I was able to add views to my layout. Now I'm trying to delete them back when a second delete button ("quitar") is pressed.
I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work for me:

```
public void quitar(View v) {
    int id = 0;
    if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
        id = viewList.get(viewList.size()-1).getId();
        viewList.remove(id);
    } 
}
```

Then I thought that before removing the view from the list maybe I should "delete it physically". I have tried this without good results:

```
public void quitar(View v) {
    int id = 0;
    RelativeLayout panelJuego = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelJuego);
    Circulo circulo = new Circulo(this, 30, 30, "#000000");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
        id = viewList.get(viewList.size()-1).getId();
        params.addRule(id);
        panelJuego.addView(circulo, params);
        viewList.remove(id);
    } 
}
```

From what I've read I sense that it may be necessary to use an ArrayAdapter but I don't know how to do it. 
This would be my attempt using an ArrayAdapter but it also does not work correctly:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Circulo> viewList = new ArrayList<Circulo>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void poner(View v) {
        ArrayAdapter<Circulo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.panelJuego, viewList);
        RelativeLayout panelJuego = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelJuego);
        Circulo circulo = new Circulo(this, 30, 30, "#FF0000");
        circulo.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
            int id = viewList.get(viewList.size()-1).getId();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);
        } 
        panelJuego.addView(circulo, params);
        viewList.add(circulo);
        adapter.add(circulo);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void quitar(View v) {
        int id = 0;
        ArrayAdapter<Circulo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.panelJuego, viewList);
        if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(viewList.size()-1));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;
        } 
    }


    public class Circulo extends View {
        private int radio = 30;
        private String color;
        int Cx, Cy;

        public Circulo(Context context, int x, int y, String color) {
            super(context);
            Cx = x;
            Cy = y;
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            canvas.drawCircle(Cx, Cy, radio, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelJuego"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="quitar"
        android:text="Quitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="poner"
        android:text="Poner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this can help to understand better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669876/removing-last-item-of-a-listview

Comment: it is better to understand if you will add more snippet of code or image illustration :)

Comment: removing view from list will not remove the view permanently as your original data source still contains that value . So after removing from list remove from your data source too

Answer (score 0):

I could finally get what I was trying to do, add red circles and delete the last one using two buttons for that. The code for that was:

```
public void poner(View v) {
    RelativeLayout panelJuego = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelJuego);
    Circulo circulo = new Circulo(this, 30, 30, "#FF0000");
    circulo.setId(View.generateViewId());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
    if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
        int id = viewList.get(viewList.size()-1).getId();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);
    } 
    panelJuego.addView(circulo, params);
    viewList.add(circulo);
    }

public void quitar(View v) {
    int id = 0;
    if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
        id = viewList.size() - 1;
        viewList.get(id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewList.remove(id);
    }
}


public class Circulo extends View {
    private int radio = 30;
    private String color;
    int Cx, Cy;

    public Circulo(Context context, int x, int y, String color) {
        super(context);
        Cx = x;
        Cy = y;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        canvas.drawCircle(Cx, Cy, radio, paint);
    }
}
```